# how to add a video on html and show the video box

Tags: html, video

In html, how to see my video animation here on the website. I am using `.mp4` on my video properties but it cannot be read on my site. The audio works but the video box is not showing up.

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxtL3.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML used to embed the video?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to insert video in your html document:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Replace movie.mp4 with your video name

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp